PyCharm Keras usage with Tensorflow
PyCharm gives this errors:


All packages are installed correctly. No errors occur during execution. Keras version selection according to compatibility matrix:

Package list:
> pip list
Package                      Version
---------------------------- --------
absl-py                      2.1.0
astunparse                   1.6.3
certifi                      2024.2.2
charset-normalizer           3.3.2
dm-tree                      0.1.8
flatbuffers                  24.3.25
gast                         0.5.4
google-pasta                 0.2.0
grpcio                       1.62.1
h5py                         3.10.0
idna                         3.6
importlib_metadata           7.1.0
keras                        3.0.0
libclang                     18.1.1
Markdown                     3.6
markdown-it-py               3.0.0
MarkupSafe                   2.1.5
mdurl                        0.1.2
ml-dtypes                    0.3.2
namex                        0.0.7
numpy                        1.26.4
opt-einsum                   3.3.0
optree                       0.11.0
packaging                    24.0
pip                          24.0
protobuf                     4.25.3
Pygments                     2.17.2
requests                     2.31.0
rich                         13.7.1
setuptools                   68.2.0
six                          1.16.0
tensorboard                  2.16.2
tensorboard-data-server      0.7.2
tensorflow                   2.16.1
tensorflow-intel             2.16.1
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.31.0
termcolor                    2.4.0
typing_extensions            4.10.0
urllib3                      2.2.1
Werkzeug                     3.0.2
wheel                        0.41.2
wrapt                        1.16.0
zipp                         3.18.1

PyCharm version: 2023.2.6

In PyCharm:
File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Invalidate and Restart

It did not help
